# smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (421, b'Service not available') while using my pycharm to send a mail with python

Tags: python, smtplib

i got the above error each time i try sending a mail using python. am somewhat new to this whole smtp thing. below is my code. please help.

```
import smtplib

my_email ="okoyekennethoptimizer@gmail.com"
password = "nmmrjdphptwfgjgb"

connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="okoyek10@yahoomail.com", msg="hello")
connection.close()
```

please help. its been giving me tough time

Comment: That's not your actual password, right?

Comment: In SMTP, all 4xx erorrs are transient. This mean you should try again later.

Comment: sometimes server may not work and then you have to try later. OR maybe your firewall or antivirus blocks access to this server. You may try to turn off firewall and antivirus

Comment: when you want to use GMail in code then it may need to create separated password for your account. Standard password may works only when you connect directly in web browser. All for security reason.

Comment: @SuperStormer, thats the app password gmail sent to me

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an "App password" after enabling 2-step auth in your Gmail. You still need to do some lookup but generally, this should help.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in:

1. Enabling less secure apps.
2. Make sure your account has 2FA.
3. Generating an app password under **My Google Account**>>**Security under** **Signing in to Google**.
4. Replace the 16-digit password with the password you've placed in the password variable.
5. Just before `connection.starttls()` add `connection.ehlo()`.

   A code for  example:

   ```
   my_email ="okoyekennethoptimizer@gmail.com"
   app_password = "16-digit-app-password"

   connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   connection.ehlo()
   connection.starttls()
   connection.login(user=my_email, password=app_password)
   ```
6. Also you **SHOULD** create `From:`, `To:`, and `Subject:` message headers, separated from the message body by a blank line.
   E.g.

   ```
   msg = "\r\n".join([
     "From: user_me@gmail.com",
     "To: user_you@gmail.com",
     "Subject: Any subject",
     "",
     "Good Evening, how are you?"
     ])
   ```